# ¿Porqué no puedo pasar un XML a JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, xml

Estoy utilizando el siguiente script para convertir un XML en un objeto JSON:

```
function xmlToJson(xml) {

    var obj = {};

    if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
        // do attributes
        if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
            obj["@attributes"] = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
            }
        }
    } else if (xml.nodeType == 4) { // cdata section
        obj = xml.nodeValue
    }

    // do children

    if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
            var nodeName = item.nodeName;
            if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
            } else {
                if (typeof(obj[nodeName].length) == "undefined") {
                    var old = obj[nodeName];
                    obj[nodeName] = [];
                    obj[nodeName].push(old);
                }
                if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) === 'object') {
                    obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

Me devuelve el siguiente error en consola:

> Uncaught TypeError: xml.hasChildNodes is not a function

El XML es tan simple como este:

```
<"?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animals>
    <dog color='Black'>
        <name>Rufus</name>
        <breed>labrador</breed>
    </dog>
    <dog breed='whippet'>
        Adopted
        <name>Marty</name>
    </dog>
    <cat color="White">
        <name>Matilda</name>
    </cat>
</animals>
```

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal para no poder trabajar con el XML?

Comment: `xml.hasChildNodes()` no lo reconoce como una función

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar de qué manera estás invocando a tu función.

Comment: En la consola de Chrome.

Comment: Si lo estás pasando desde un string tal vez necesites usar `DOMParser()` antes.

Comment: No. Tal cual. Con tags de apertura y cierre. Tal y como está

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debido a que en tu consola estás enviando un objeto diferente a documento XML te arroja dicho error, para ello podrías usar `jQuery` para realizar conversión.

```js
function xmlToJson(xml) {

    var obj = {};

    if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
        // do attributes
        if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
            obj["@attributes"] = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
            }
        }
    } else if (xml.nodeType == 4) { // cdata section
        obj = xml.nodeValue
    }

    // do children

    if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
            var nodeName = item.nodeName;
            if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
            } else {
                if (typeof(obj[nodeName].length) == "undefined") {
                    var old = obj[nodeName];
                    obj[nodeName] = [];
                    obj[nodeName].push(old);
                }
                if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) === 'object') {
                    obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};

var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><animals><dog color='Black'><name>Rufus</name><breed>labrador</breed></dog><dog breed='whippet'>Adopted<name>Marty</name></dog><cat color=\"White\"><name>Matilda</name></cat></animals>";

console.log(xmlToJson($.parseXML(xml)));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [jQuery.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que la variable `xml` que pasas a la funcin no es un `XML` DOM DOC y por lo tanto no tiene la funcion `hasChildNodes()`

prueba esto:

```
var text= '<"?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
'<animals>'+
    '<dog color="Black">'+
        '<name>Rufus</name>'+
        '<breed>labrador</breed>'+
   ' </dog>'+
    '<dog breed="whippet">'+
        'Adopted'+
        '<name>Marty</name>'+
   ' </dog>'
    '<cat color="White">'+
        '<name>Matilda</name>'+
    '</cat>'+
'</animals>';

 var    parser = new DOMParser();
 var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

function xmlToJson(xml) {
  ...
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(xmlToJson(xmlDoc)));
```

Comment: pero entonces tengo que transformar el xml. antes de pasárselo a la función?

Comment: como lo obtienes? mira este ejemplo https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_loadxmldoc2. lo que si tienes que estar seguro que lo que le pases a la funcion tiene que ser un xml DOM Document